# Подскажите что за символ и как его ввести?

Tags: php

В видеокусе наткнулся на неизвестный мне символ и не знаю как его получить в PhpStorm[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: этот символ получается при сериализации видимо и уметь печатать вам его не надо

Comment: Эта строка проводит десериализацию, она должна создать объект с пустыми полями, следовательно обычный ноль (0) должен прокатить?

Comment: угу. это и есть ноль )  ..... можете отсюда скопировать если надо http://php.net/manual/ru/function.serialize.php#66147

Comment: Точно, спасибо, а то что левее - это большая буква O, а не ноль, как я думал раньше.